# Why is my AJAX form refreshing the page when I submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am creating a simple Follow/Unfollow system, everything works fine in the sense that it inserts the row and deletes the row when I follow/unfollow, but for some reason it refreshes the page every time, even though I'm using `e.preventDefault();`, why is this? Thanks

```
<div class="followBtns showFollowDiv">
   <form method="POST" action="">
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" name="username">
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $grabUser['username']; ?>" name="following">
     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s'); ?>" name="date">

     <div id="followButtonContainer">
       <?php if ($is_following): ?>
         <button class="followBtn" type="button" value="unfollow" name="action">Unfollow</button>
       <?php else: ?>
          <button class="followBtn" type="button" value="follow" name="action">Follow</button>
       <?php endif; ?>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
```

This is my script at the bottom of my webpage:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SCRIPT FOR FOLLOWING A USER ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~//
 $(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Follow function is working..");
  $(".followBtn").on("click", function(e) {
    // Prevent the default behavior of the button
    e.preventDefault();

    // Check if the button triggers the login modal
    if ($(this).hasClass('followBtn-signin')) {
        $('#loginModal').modal('show'); // Show login modal
        return;
    }

    var followButton = $(this);
    var formDataFollow = {
      'FollowUser': true,
      'username': $('input[name="username"]').val(),
      'following': $('input[name="following"]').val(),
      'date': $('input[name="date"]').val(),
      'action': $(this).val()
  };
    console.log(formDataFollow);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Blog/resources/PHP/FollowUserPHP.php",
        data: formDataFollow,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#followButtonContainer').html(response.button);
            // Toggle the button text based on the response
            if (response.status === "followed") {
                // Increment the follower count on the frontend
                var followerCountElement = $('.follower-count');
                followerCountElement.text(parseInt(followerCountElement.text()) + 1);
            } else if (response.status === "unfollowed") {
                // Decrement the follower count on the frontend
                var followerCountElement = $('.follower-count');
                followerCountElement.text(parseInt(followerCountElement.text()) - 1);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

and this is my FollowUserPHP.php:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 require_once '/var/www/vhosts/ggweb3.xyz/httpdocs/PHP/connect.php';

 if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['following']) && isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['action'])) {
  $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $following = filter_var($_POST['following'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $date = filter_var($_POST['date'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $action = $_POST['action'];

// Check if the user is already following the viewed user
$stmt_check = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS following_count FROM followers WHERE username = :username AND following = :following");
$stmt_check->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt_check->bindParam(':following', $following, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt_check->execute();
$fetchFollowing = $stmt_check->fetch();
$is_following = ($fetchFollowing['following_count'] > 0);

if ($action == 'follow' && !$is_following) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `followers` (`username`, `following`, `date`) VALUES (:username, :following, :date)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':following', $following, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $response = array('status' => 'followed', 'button' => '<button class="followBtn" type="button" value="unfollow" name="action">Unfollow</button>');
} elseif ($action == 'unfollow' && $is_following) {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM `followers` WHERE `username` = :username AND `following` = :following");
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':following', $following, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $response = array('status' => 'unfollowed', 'button' => '<button class="followBtn" type="button" value="follow" name="action">Follow</button>');
   } else {
    // Invalid action value or user is already following/unfollowing
    $response = array('error' => 'Invalid action or user is already following/unfollowing');
}
} else {
// Missing parameters
$response = array('error' => 'Missing parameters');
}

// Output the response as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: to prevent form submission, you stop the `submit` event, not a `click` event

Comment: You don't need this line `followButton.closest('form').submit();` because you are executing POST using AJAX. Also, you need to have `<form onsubmit="return myFormSubmit()" />` kind of function, returning false but doing your AJAX instead. And lastly, you don't need to handle `submit` button click. It must trigger form submit that you will then process with `myFormSubmit` mentioned above.

Comment: @RAllen We have had [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) for 20 years. I think it's high time to use it instead of returning false as if it were the 1990s.

Comment: @some, would you mind showing me `some` official documentation that says that `return false` is obsolete or deprecated? If `preventDefault` exists, it doesn't mean it is the best for all possible scenarios.

Comment: @RAllen You can do whatever you want with your own  code, even use `eval` if you want. But it is considered [bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).  It's so bad that there is an option in content security policy to prevent it.

Comment: @RAllen I followed your advice and removed `followButton.closest('form').submit();` now it submits without refreshing page, thanks but I'm still having a hard time getting it to update the button action live

Comment: @RAllen code has been updated on here, I managed to make it so that the Follow button gets clicked and then the AJAX replaces the follow button with the unfollow button from the PHP, but when I click the Unfollow button it doesn't do anything until I refresh the page and click it again, then it unfollows the user, kinda annoying but thats as close I can get it

Comment: @kbmzeeC0de, try adding a console log at the top of your onclick function to see if it is invoked for the second time. Also, add `console.log(response);` as the first line of the `success` function to make sure that PHP returns what you expect, to change the button from `unfollow` to `follow`. And finally, check the console for any errors.

Comment: @some where in the document you've referenced is mentioned that `return false` is a bad practice? Also, please look into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: @some also check this document https://api.jquery.com/on/ and specifically this sentence `Returning false from an event handler will automatically call event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault().`.

Comment: Did you remove some of your code, because there is nothing in the code that reloads the page. You must have something  elsewhere that does the reload.

Comment: @chrwahl Yes the code has been updated, the "Follow" button no longer refreshes the page and works fine for submitting the follow, but then it replaces the Follow button with the Unfollow button which then doesn't submit unless I refresh the page and hit the Unfollow button again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `$('#followButtonContainer').html(response.button);` in the AJAX callback you replace the follow button with a new button. This new button does not have the event listener (that is create when the page loads), so you either you need to add an event listener to that new button or have the event listener on a parent element that is not replaced.

Here, I add the event listener again in the callback (the code only works for inserting the unfollow button because the AJAX request i static with a data URI):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Follow function is working..");
  $(".followBtn").on("click", followClicked);
});

function followClicked(e) {
  // Check if the button triggers the login modal
  if ($(this).hasClass('followBtn-signin')) {
    $('#loginModal').modal('show'); // Show login modal
    return;
  }

  var followButton = $(this);
  var formDataFollow = {
    'FollowUser': true,
    'username': $('input[name="username"]').val(),
    'following': $('input[name="following"]').val(),
    'date': $('input[name="date"]').val(),
    'action': $(this).val()
  };
  console.log(formDataFollow);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: `data:application/json,{"button":"<button class='followBtn' type='button' value='unfollow' name='action'>Unfollow</button>","status":"followed"}`,
    data: formDataFollow,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      $('#followButtonContainer').html(response.button);
      $(".followBtn").on("click", followClicked);
      // Toggle the button text based on the response
      if (response.status === "followed") {
        // Increment the follower count on the frontend
        var followerCountElement = $('.follower-count');
        followerCountElement.text(parseInt(followerCountElement.text()) + 1);
      } else if (response.status === "unfollowed") {
        // Decrement the follower count on the frontend
        var followerCountElement = $('.follower-count');
        followerCountElement.text(parseInt(followerCountElement.text()) - 1);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="followBtns showFollowDiv">
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="hidden" value="user01" name="username">
    <input type="hidden" value="user02" name="following">
    <input type="hidden" value="2024/03/25 15:00:00" name="date">

    <div id="followButtonContainer">
      <button class="followBtn" type="button" value="follow" name="action">Follow</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, but I'm curious, How does it submit without page refresh without the `preventDefault`?

Comment: In your code the button has the `type="button"`, so it has no default behavior. If the button should submit the form you should either remove the type attribute or set it to `type="submit"`. So much for a long discussion under the question :-)